# iOS: NavigationStack.navigationDestination breaks ARKit Session used in RealityKit ARView

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit, swiftui-navigationstack

The following code is described as doing (this is related to Reality Kit ARView, although I am accessing the underlying ARKit Session as you will see):

- App opens to a .nonAR ARView `FirstARView`
- This will show a red background with a blue box showing a single side of the box face on
- There will be some red text which says `Press the button`, when you press this the app uses a `NavigationStack.navigationDestination` to open a second RealityKit ARView `MagicARView`

Before the `MagicARView` opens the following occurs to the ARKit session from .nonAR ARView `FirstARView`

1. Pause
2. Change camera mode to .AR
3. Change the background to be .CameraFeed()
4. Run()
5. Pause()

**Note on why you have to do the above steps 1 to 5**:
I had a previous issue when switching between a view with a .nonAR view and an .AR view where the camera feed on the .AR view was just black - the only way to overcome this seems to be running the above steps on the underlying ARKit session before switching to the second .AR view.

Now when the second .AR `MagicARView` opens there will be a large blue box which appears at [0,0,0].

**Expected behaviour:** you can move around the room (eg: move behind a partial wall) and the box will be occluded by the wall.

**Actual behaviour:** you can move around the room (eg: move behind a partial wall) and the box IS NOT occluded by the wall - occlusion is broken.

**My assumption:** Even through you see the .nonAR ARView `FirstARView` disappearing, and even through I go to great lengths to set both the arView in the FirstController and even the FirstController itself to nil - something is being held onto incorrectly in the underlying ARKit Session (apparently there is only one per app...)

**My solution and question:** See the second code block for the solution - if you remove the `.navigationDestination` and use conditionals in the `ContentView` it appears to resolve the issue. Does anyone understand the inc`.navigationDestination` and ARKit session and why this is the case? Note you obviously do not even need to pause() and change the camera when doing it this way.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import ARKit

let configuration: ARWorldTrackingConfiguration = {
    let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    
    if (ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsSceneReconstruction(ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.SceneReconstruction.mesh)) {
        config.sceneReconstruction = .mesh
    }
    
    config.planeDetection = [.vertical, .horizontal]
    
    return config
}()

class FirstViewController {
    weak var arView: ARView?
}

class FirstViewControllerWrapper {
    var firstController: FirstViewController?
    
    init() {
        firstController = FirstViewController()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var loadSecondView: Bool = false
    
    var firstViewControllerWrapper: FirstViewControllerWrapper?
    
    init () {
        firstViewControllerWrapper = FirstViewControllerWrapper()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            ZStack{
                FirstARView(firstViewController: firstViewControllerWrapper!.firstController!)
                    .onDisappear(){
                        print("First view is disappearing")
                    }
                Button(action: {
                    firstViewControllerWrapper?.firstController!.arView?.session.pause()
                    firstViewControllerWrapper?.firstController!.arView?.cameraMode = .ar
                    firstViewControllerWrapper?.firstController!.arView?.environment.background = .cameraFeed()
                    firstViewControllerWrapper?.firstController!.arView?.session.run(configuration)
                    firstViewControllerWrapper?.firstController!.arView?.session.pause()
                    firstViewControllerWrapper?.firstController!.arView = nil
                    firstViewControllerWrapper?.firstController = nil
                    loadSecondView = true
                    
                }) {
                    Text("Press the button").background(.red)
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $loadSecondView) {
                MagicARView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MagicARView: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero, cameraMode: .ar, automaticallyConfigureSession: true)
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.occlusion)

        let boxMesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.5)
        let boxMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: .blue, isMetallic: false)
        let model = ModelEntity(mesh: boxMesh, materials: [boxMaterial])
        let modelAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: [0.2,0.2,0.2])
        modelAnchor.addChild(model)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(modelAnchor)
        arView.session.run(configuration)
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}

struct FirstARView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    weak var firstViewController: FirstViewController?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
    
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero, cameraMode: .nonAR, automaticallyConfigureSession: true)
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.occlusion)

        let boxMesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.5)
        let boxMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: .blue, isMetallic: false)
        let model = ModelEntity(mesh: boxMesh, materials: [boxMaterial])
        let modelAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: [0.2,0.2,0.2])
        modelAnchor.addChild(model)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(modelAnchor)
        arView.session.run(configuration)
        arView.environment.background = .color(.red)
        firstViewController!.arView = arView
        
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}
```

**Solution?**

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import ARKit

let configuration: ARWorldTrackingConfiguration = {
    let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    
    if (ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsSceneReconstruction(ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.SceneReconstruction.mesh)) {
        config.sceneReconstruction = .mesh
    }
    
    config.planeDetection = [.vertical, .horizontal]
    
    return config
}()

class FirstViewController {
    weak var arView: ARView?
}

class FirstViewControllerWrapper {
    var firstController: FirstViewController?
    
    init() {
        firstController = FirstViewController()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var loadSecondView: Bool = false
    
    var firstViewControllerWrapper: FirstViewControllerWrapper?
    
    init () {
        firstViewControllerWrapper = FirstViewControllerWrapper()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            ZStack{
                if (!loadSecondView) {
                    FirstARView(firstViewController: firstViewControllerWrapper!.firstController!)
                        .onDisappear(){
                            print("First view is disappearing")
                        }
                }
                if (loadSecondView){
                    MagicARView()
                }
                Button(action: {
         
                    loadSecondView = true
                    
                }) {
                    Text("Press the button").background(.red)
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct MagicARView: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero, cameraMode: .ar, automaticallyConfigureSession: true)
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.occlusion)

        let boxMesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.5)
        let boxMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: .blue, isMetallic: false)
        let model = ModelEntity(mesh: boxMesh, materials: [boxMaterial])
        let modelAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: [0.2,0.2,0.2])
        modelAnchor.addChild(model)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(modelAnchor)
        arView.session.run(configuration)
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}

struct FirstARView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    weak var firstViewController: FirstViewController?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
    
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero, cameraMode: .nonAR, automaticallyConfigureSession: true)
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.occlusion)

        let boxMesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.5)
        let boxMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: .blue, isMetallic: false)
        let model = ModelEntity(mesh: boxMesh, materials: [boxMaterial])
        let modelAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: [0.2,0.2,0.2])
        modelAnchor.addChild(model)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(modelAnchor)
        arView.session.run(configuration)
        arView.environment.background = .color(.red)
        firstViewController!.arView = arView
        
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: There might be a leak, check how many times the init for FirstViewControllerWrapper is called

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using prints in the init() I see it is called once.